# Is Spring Boot blocking on database operations?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, asynchronous

I am building a backend server with Spring Boot and MongoDB, basically according to this tutorial https://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-mongodb-data-rest/.

All my repositories are annotated with @RepositoryRestResource. The controllers for each REST repository are annotated with @RestController.

My question is, are the database operations in a REST application in Spring Boot blocking or non-blocking? That is, do the threads that handle one specific HTTP request (e.g. GET ) just idle when waiting for a response from the MongoDB, or do they resume to some thread pool in the meanwhile?

I have been looking up the documentation, but I could not seem to find a specification for the thread model in this case. I have also been looking at tutorials for "Making an asynchronous application in Spring Boot", but it didn't seem like they quite covered this specific issue.

Comment: Have you looked into [spring web flux](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html)? you can still use spring boot with mongodb reactive  [Mongo DB reactive](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-data-mongodb-reactive)

Comment: Currently our server only needs very simple results from the database, so all of the REST requests that are mapped to the DB methods use the keyword-driven methods that are implicitly autogenerated by spring (e.g, findByID(id) etc). Will these then automatically be non-blocking requests if I use MongoDB reactive instead of regular MongoDB for Spring?

Comment: I understand you are using spring data libraries. Yes using reactive libraries will make it reactive but you got it change the return types to reactive streams such as Flux and Mono.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The web layer can be either *blocking* on *non-blocking*, based on the stack you are using.

If you are using a blocking stack for your web layer (for example, one based on *spring-boot-starter-web*), `DeferredResult` can be used to make sure you don't run out of request handling threads.

See the snippet below for sample usage:

```
@RestController
public class EntityController {

    private ExecutorService executor;

    @GetMapping
    public DeferredResult<Entity> getEntity(/**params**/) {
        DeferredResult<Entity> result = new DeferredResult<>();
        // request thread freed and returned to the request handling thread pool
        executor.execute(() -> output.setResult(entity)
        return result;
    }

}
```

For a complete example on `DeferredResult`, see [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-deferred-result)

Comment: Thank you very much! So if I understand it correctly, I can either change the stack to use the MongoDB Reactive implementation, or make my code implement the pattern for DeferredResult. Any recommendations on which one is easier to use?

Comment: @wasp Yes, you understood correctly. Regarding the implementation, weather you should go blocking or non-blocking depends on your business needs. Considering you are already on a  blocking stack, using DeferredResult should be easier from an implementation perspective.